# mysql query in single command to get sum per name

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql I need to get the sum of columns but could not get in single command

I have a table of

```
Name, Class, zone1,zone2,zone3,zone4
X, 1, 10,20,30,40
X, 2, 50,60,70,80
Y, 1, 20,30,40,50
Y, 3, 70,80,90,10
```

I need a single mysql command to get the sum of zone1 to zone4 per name and class

```
X,1,Sum
X,2,Sum
Y,1,Sum
Y,3,sum.
... etc
```

I tried select 
(Thanks  I have modified query to )
    select Name,Class,zone+zone2+zone3+zone4 as Total from table;

Now how to get the result as (though i can do in php, but any method to do in mysql itself)
    X,1,Sum,2,Sum
    Y,1,Sum,3,sum
    ... etc

Comment: Just remove the `SUM()` i.e. `select Name,Class,zone1+zone2+zone3+zone4 as Total from table;`

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names, alarm bells should start ringing. Consider revising your schema design.

Comment: A |                1 |  90.534309 |
|   A |                2 |  17.153140 |
|   A |                3 |  A.945187 |
|   A |                4 |  13.245908 |
|   B |                1 |  95.544470 |
|   B |                2 |   8.145934 |
|   B |                3 |   9.378935 |
|   B |                4 |   9.896046 |    How to group by Name. so that i get as B,1,95.544470,2,8.145934,3,9.378935,4,9.896046

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chnage your query to `select Name,Class,(zone+zone2+zone3+zone4) as Total from table;` and try again

Comment: A | 1 | 90.534309 | | A | 2 | 17.153140 | | A | 3 | A.945187 | | A | 4 | 13.245908 | | B | 1 | 95.544470 | | B | 2 | 8.145934 | | B | 3 | 9.378935 | | B | 4 | 9.896046 | How to group by Name. so that i get as B,1,95.544470,2,8.145934,3,9.378935,4,9.896046